# Graceful exit server when using Django's autoreloader

Tags: python, django

I am using a custom Django `runserver` command that is supposed to run a bunch of cleanup functions upon termination. This works fine as long as I don't use the autoreloader: by server catches the KeyboardInterrupt exception properly and exits gracefully.

However, if I use Django's autoreloader, the reloader seems to simply kill the server thread without properly terminating it (as far as I can tell, it doesn't have any means to do this).

This seems inherently unsafe, so I can't really believe that there's not a better way of handling this.

Can I somehow use the autoreloader functionality without having my server thread be killed uncleanly?

Comment: I don't know what kind of cleanup you are talking about. But you should not expect any thread to close gracefully neither with `runserver` nor with a WSGI server when in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `atexit` module to catch the termination. It should work for everything which acts like SIGINT or SIGTERM, SIGKILL cannot be interrupted (but should not be sent by any auto-restart script without sending SIGTERM before).

Comment: This worked beautifully with django's reloader, thanks!